# Jquery addClass after images loaded

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm working on a multiplayer card game. What I want to do is to get this:

```
$("#player_cards img").on('click', ->
$(this).toggleClass 'selected')
```

working.`img` represents cards here. Initially, on the page there are no cards, they are loaded using websocket after a player bets and another player joins the game, so I guess they are not in the DOM

this doesn't work either:

```
$("#player_cards img").load( ->
  $("#player_cards img").on('click', ->
    $(this).toggleClass 'selected')
  )
```

Update:

I just have tried imagesLoaded, which hi5place suggested, it also doesn't work

the code, I tried

```
imagesLoaded("#player_cards img", ->
  $(this).click ->
    $(this).toggleClass 'selected'
  )
```

Comment: you can use .delay() to provide some delay to your in toggleclass..see here http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: that is not an option because, nobody knows when players want to play

Comment: why do you have a click handler

Comment: because I need to know which card has been chosen

Answer (score 0):

Home this jQuery plugin can help you

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

```
JavaScript is all like "You images done yet or what?"
```